# unable to assign IAM and S3 Bucket policies to List/Get/Put

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

It has been 2 hours trying to figure it out. I have an IAM User s3readonly with following attached policy :

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MyBucket"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MyBucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

and S3 Bucket Policy for MyBucket (changed names):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow Read Only for s3readonly user",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::MyAccountId:user/s3readonly"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MyBucket"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::MyAccountId:user/s3readonly"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::MyBucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

However, even after so many changes I have arrived at above after, when I login as s3readonly, I get "Access Denied" in the S3 Dashboard

Can anyone help?

Comment: based on [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-how-to-grant-access-to-an-amazon-s3-bucket/), console access to s3 also requires  `ListAllMyBuckets` (in addition to `GetBucketLocation` which you already have).

Comment: oh, "s3:ListBucket" doesnt suffice? let me check

Comment: coesn't help! I added the ListAllMyBuckets in addition to ListBucket in the IAM Policy for the user. still Access Denied.

Comment: @How did you add it? For the resource you need to use "*" as shown in the link. It says that it must be for  "for all resources in Amazon S3"

Comment: can we have the revised bucket / iam polcy? I think you were mentioning a change in bucket policy, wherein I mistook for IAM policy

Comment: Not sure. Just check which one would work.

Comment: no. not helpful at all - I tried the s3 bucket policy as in the link, it complaint of missing principal. Anyway thanks

Comment: umm, worked. but not worked quite - actually I can now see in the AWS Console S3 section,
my bucket MyBucket, and the contents underneath.
but I also see all other buckets, albeit cant list view the contents underneath them,

I had wanted to only see one bucket and not others that I see too, even if I can list the content or read them which is fine,

Comment: good. its a good step closer to the solution.

Comment: thanks, just trying to figure out if I only can see names of buckets I own/want. then I'll answer my question with credits and help from you :)